# Can the Thomann T.AMP E400 be bridged?

Tags: engineering

I'm selling my [T.AMP E400](http://www.thomann.de/ie/the_tamp_e400.htm) and I've been asked a question which is over my head as far as my knowledge of powered amplifiers goes.

> Can this amp be bridged, and if so, what is the output at 4 and 8 ohm?

I wouldn't have a clue what the answer is or how to find out. (I do not want to have to buy any equipment to test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Close-up from the 360° view:

[image: The T-Amp E400 backside switches]

Where you can see the switch between stereo (STE), parallel and bridged. The specifications in this mode are 380W @ 8Ω / 240W @ 16Ω. You can't operate it safely on 4Ω in that mode. (Probably, the shortcut protection would just shut it down.)

Comment: Why do you say `"You can't operate it safely on 4Ω in that mode"`? How do you come to that conclusion? And where did you get `"380W @ 8Ω / 240W @ 16Ω"` from? Is that from a product specification/manual or past experience/testing?

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers#Bridged_amplifier). The channels of an amplifier in bridged mode (in which they're effectively wired in series) together have twice the power (fairly obvious), but they also require twice the speaker impedance.

Answer (score 0):

When you bridge an amp the load in 8 ohm is as high as using 4 ohm speakers in stereo,therefor without getting technical 4 ohm bridged for a cheap entery level pa amp is as hard a load a 2 ohm in stereo, no cheap amp beside nad amps can handle 2 ohm loads.

E400=400 watt max E800=800 watt max Right ;-)